# Reverse Proxy with Apex and Weblogic

Tags: apache, proxy, weblogic, oracle-apex

I have multiple applications running in Oracle APEX 5. They are served through ORDS and Weblogic 12.2. Then a web front end to serve the reverse proxy. It may sound dumb, but that's what we were tasked to do. I used mod_proxy to get the reverse proxy going, but I'm having issues hiding the application number. The original url is devapp101.cloud.com:7003/ords/f?p=101 . What I want users to navigate is devapex.cloud.com what I have is devapex.cloud.com/ords/f?p=101 . Here is the config I've got right now. What can I do to have users only use devapex.cloud.com?

```
###devapex.cloud.com
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin admin@cloud.com

  ServerName devapex.cloud.com

  ErrorLog logs/devapex.error_log

  CustomLog logs/devapex.access_log common

  ### re-direct to the appropriate server

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  #RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-SSL true

  ProxyPass        / http://devapp101.cloud.com:7003/ 

  ProxyPassReverse / http://devapp101.cloud.com:7003/

</VirtualHost>
```

I've looked at mod_rewrite, but I'm not seeing how that can do what I want to happen. Please excuse my noobness here, but I've searched everywhere for this scenario, and I have not found it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure 'Oracle WebLogic Server Proxy Plug-In' to proxy requests from web front end to WebLogic.

Check the document : 

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/webtier/develop-plugin/toc.htm

What is your web front end to serve the reverse proxy?

Check the documents to match the middleware of your web front end.

(If 'Apache HTTP Server', check 'Configuring the Plug-In for Apache HTTP Server'.)

Comment: I've had no issue getting the connection to WebLogic. My issue is being able to include the /ords/f?p=101 in the proxy address. I'm using Apache currently, but I'm not opposed to trying new things like nginx or OHS. I installed OHS, but I'm not familiar enough with it and it seems like more work then it's worth being that I'm going to be housing 10's of these on our web front end. I believe I would need a domain for each one. All of these will be within our internal network.